# Push notifications from ASP.Net page to different platforms using Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, cordova, azure, push-notification

I have a working mobile application in Cordova using Azure. **I have managed to implement push notifications from the app itself in Cordova i.e. I have managed to make the users which have the app on their phone register for push notifications and also add items to a database and send notifications to all registered users**. My aim, however, is now to instead send notifications to these users from an ASP.NET web page which acts as a CMS and will be used by the admin.

By following this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-android-notify-users/

I did set up a Web API. However, this uses an Android client which sends notifications to selected users upon logging in. For me this is useless. I would like to know if its possible to re-create the equivalent in an ASP.NET environment using C# (or perhaps Javascript?). Given the application I am developing, I cannot have the person who would be adding to the database use a Cordova Mobile App himself but rather a sort of CMS in an ASP.NET website. I would appreciate some kind of help or some sort of starting points. Any help would be appreciated :)

More info: the administrator would be adding 'news items' into the database. This info should be sent to all users who are currently registered with our mobile service for push notifications and for that particular news category.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Notification Hubs for the push notifications then yes, you can send to it from ASP.NET, or actually lots of different languages. There is also a REST based API in addition to libraries to help with this.

Take a look at [this tutorial for sending notifications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-notify-users/) to users. It uses a WebAPI to then send the calls out, but the approach should be adaptable for your needs.